# How can I convert GeoJSON data to GPX format

Tags: pgrouting, convert, geojson, gpx

I want to know how I can convert GeoJSON data to GPX format.

Comment: Do I miss something: Your question is too broad. Are you looking for some converter or code sample to do the job?

Comment: yeah I need a code sample to change geoOSON data to GPX

Comment: @rajansthapit Please do put that on your question.

Comment: Posted the incorrect link, the api is free:
https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/geokoala/overview

Answer (score 3):

A general answer: use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) from command line like:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx input.geojson
```

Or, try finding a library in your language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free REST API for this

Simply POST GeoJson Data to an endpoint, and view the POI in Augmented Reality browsers(wikitude) , google earth, google maps or any GPX(track and route), KML, ARML supported app in real time.

https://www.mashape.com/geokoala/geokoala/overview

Just create an AppKey, and check out the code samples in curl,java,node,php,python,objective-c,ruby, and .net.